# Pexpect not matching (control codes)

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, pexpect

Pexpect script running against a Casa CMTS/router.

I have working implementations of this script for Cisco and Adva devices, so I know the technique is sound, but for some reason i'm having issues with a specific expectation.

I'm trying to match a simple

```
:
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
def handleAllPrompts(self):
    while self.child.after == ":":
        print "waiting"
        self.child.expect(":", 20)
    try:
        self.child.expect("\>\ *$|#\ *$|\$\ *$", 20)
    except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT as e:
        print self.child.before
```

This is supposed to automatically handle the "more" prompt when doing something like a `show run` that has multiple screens of output.

Pexpect crashes with this info:

```
before (last 100 chars): 'sis downstream channel utilization"\r\nalias save "copy run start"\r\nalias scm "show cable modem"\r\n:\x1b[K'
```

I'm trying to detect the last colon (`:\x1b[K`), however as you can see it's a colon+term control code.

But doing:

```
def handleAllPrompts(self):
    while self.child.after == ":\x1b[K":
        print "waiting"
        self.child.expect(":\x1b[K", 20)
    try:
        self.child.expect("\>\ *$|#\ *$|\$\ *$", 20)
    except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT as e:
        print self.child.before
```

Doesn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you do before calling `handleAllPrompts()`? The `.after` and `.before` only makes sense after `.expect()`.

Comment: self.child.expect('[Pp]assword:')
        self.child.sendline(self.password)
        self.handleAllPrompts()
        self.child.setecho(True)

Comment: How do you want to *automatically handle the `more` prompt*? I cannot figure that out based on your `handleAllPrompts()` code. Or what's the intended functionality of `handleAllPrompts()`?